# Await Successful updateProfile to Update Document data

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase & Flutter, I store the displayName of a user on the auth Profile of firebase, as well as separately storing the first name and last name on the user doc.

When a user wants to change their first or last name I need to update the auth Profile displayName as well as the fields on the user's doc.

However, changing the profile with updateProfile returns a `Future<void>`, so I can't figure out how to conditionally await to determine whether to write to the user doc.  For instance:

```
thisUser.updateProfile(displayName: displayName).then((val) {
  DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
    firstName,
    lastName,
  );
  return;
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return;
});
```

If a user has not recently authenticated, an error catches, which is all good, I initiate re-authenticating. However, in that case, I do not want to update the doc right away with the updateUserData function.  However, in the above code, updateUserData is called regardless of success or error of updateProfile.

How can I call updateUserData ONLY if updateProfile is successful?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Flutter auth SDK has a listener `userChanges` that you can use to update your `doc`:

```js
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .userChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      // Update you doc here
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage). Basically it will trigger everytime something changes regarding the user. That way you don't need to await your `updateProfile`. This would be a general solution for your problem.

Comment: Now, I did see an update on this with the latest update, in the past this didn't register updateProfile as a change.  However, I think that's been corrected in some way.  However, this is already my user stream; and users may change email, password, display name or custom claims I've added. I'd rather find something direct as opposed either re-writing everything to catch a change or determining some strategy for determining what changed specifically. (if it exists, this is my last resort I'd say I guess.)

Comment: Clarification: Maybe I need to get over this, but I guess I dislike the idea of re-writing the display names to the doc everytime any user change occurs.  I guess this is a solution of last resort.

Comment: I would not consider this as a bad solution. I use in every of my Apps and in every language and platform such a listener to update the user data. Those changes don't happen so often so the benefit of simplicity is more than the cost of 1-2 writes each time the app opens or the user changes his name (probably the most less change in any app)

Comment: Tarik-I'm already subscribed to userChanges() as my primary user provider.  It's the catchall for any change, auth (login/logout), profile and otherwise. Which means I'd be calling it multiple times a day for my users.   Do you just evaluate for doc mis-matches and then trigger the update if needed?  It's just a process that feels like 99/100 times isn't going to trigger to actually write, but I evaluate for constantly, and I'm surprised there isn't a cleaner approach.

Comment: I guess I could just write a function to write on any mismatch. Maybe I should look for a cloud solution.  I feel like anytime I do this this kind of thing (writing a local function to keep a doc in line with auth or some other doc), I wind up going to cloud functions.